# Rewrite Rule in htaccess all works except the last rule

Tags: .htaccess

Mine actual code is this and the last rule dsnt work properly, someone can help please?,

A lot of thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^diamantesgould.net [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.diamantesgould.net/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?po=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^categories/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?ca=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^videos/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /video.php?movie=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^galleries/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /galleries.php?gallery=$1 [NC]
```

**NOTE: The problem is that it shows the same page by typing mydomain.com/galleries or mydomain.com/galleries/1 or mydomain.com/galleries/1/2/3/4 ... It always shows the galleries page (mydomain.com/galleries)**

Answer (score 0):

I see something that may not be rigth in your regexp:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ should be [a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+, - is a special char so must be escaped to be used only as a char
```

Comment: And i you replace [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ by [a-z0-9_\-]+ and add [NC] add the end of your regexp the NC means the case check is escaped (so thats why A-Z is not necessary). Do not forget to change each regexp because in your example they all carry the same - char not escaped

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^diamantesgould\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.diamantesgould.net/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /index.php?po=$1  
RewriteRule ^categories/([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /index.php?ca=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^videos/([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /video.php?movie=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^galleries/([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /galleries.php?gallery=$1 [NC]

Comment: and what if you write RewriteRule ^galleries/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /galleries.php?gallery=$1 [NC] (just a little trick)

Comment: I'm completly at lost sorry, try to add QSA ([NC, QSA]) to your rules, QSA is used to append the value in url to the rewrited url, so it should not change anything but doesn't hurt to try

Comment: The url you want to try is www.diamantesgould.net/galleries/plants-and-flowers?

Comment: I said that because http://www.diamantesgould.net/galleries.php return a 404 not found error, and if galleries.php is the script you want to call there is a problem because your webserver does not find it.